# Python Flask send alert without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, python, flask, message

I recently started with Flask and web servers and webpages in general. Is there a way to pop up an alert message on the web page through server without reloading the page. The current ways I know of are:

1) Reloading the whole page and calling alert() function in javascript
2) Using flask's flash() function to send text to place holders in the page.

Both of above require reloading the whole page. I guessing if there is a method we would do something in the return call instead of return render_template(...).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit [Not Duplicate]: This question is not asking how to use AJAX with Flask. At the time of the question I wasn't aware of using flask to do this.

Comment: When would you want this alert message to pop up?

Comment: I want the alert message after the server is done sending an email that was requested from the page.

Comment: Okay you should look into AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to send an AJAX request to the server and have your flask code return a response that your JavaScript can manipulate and modify the page.

Here is a good resource for [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I found an example on: http://runnable.com/UiPhLHanceFYAAAP/how-to-perform-ajax-in-flask-for-python